# JSONField in Serializers of Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a serializer which has only one JSONField

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    data = serializers.JSONField()
```

When I am trying to use this serializer in the shell as -

```
>>> s = DataSerializer(data={"name": "Tom"})
>>> s.is_valid()
False
>>> s.errors
{'data': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please bear with me if its a too simple question as I am new to using DRF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way you have to send the data in:

```
s = DataSerializer(data={"data" : {"name": "Tom"}})
```

Perhaps, your choice to name your jsonfield `data' confused you little bit here.

The parameter `data` when constructing the serializer is just a parameter which it uses to set the data to serialize.

When you call `is_valid`, it looks at the data passed in to the serializer and tries to find the JSONField named `data` in this case.

If you renamed it to let's say jsondata, it would try to find jsondata in the data. In that case, you would do:

```
s = DataSerializer(data={"jsondata" : {"name": "Tom"}})
```

Hope it is clear.

Comment: why do we need to pass the extra data key there? is it that every serializer has a default parameter of data?

Comment: Your are not passing extra data key. Rename the data in your serializer to something else and you might understand better. I will include brief explanation in the answer.